# 3ds wifi network login?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I've been having issues with my ds, connecting to wifi that involves a webpage login.
It never used to have the problem, and then all of a sudden it has just quit.
I've tried everything I can think of to resolve it, but it's gotten me nowhere. There's so little information on this problem, I'm guessing because so few people know how to get around it, but I've seen that it is not uncommon at all.... any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried using the Browser to go to Google or some other website while connected to the network? It will usually redirect you to the login page of the network.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly what I do. It just doesnt redirect me, and it usually just pops up with "the internet browser can't be used at this time" and forces me to exit.